# Sorting an array with elements ranging from 0 to 9999

Tags: c++, algorithm

I recently stumbled upon a C++ problem. Here goes.

> Suppose you know that all the values in an integer array fall into the range 0 to 9999.
>   Show that it is possible to write a O(N) algorithm to sort arrays with this restriction

To my understanding an algorithm of O(N) is one where you go through a certain set of O(1) operations N times. Now for the life of me I can't comprehend how you would go about writing a program that sorts an array of numbers with respect to O(N). Sorting in its most basic form consists of comparing numbers with each other and there is no algorithm for doing that in one iteration and ending up with a sorted array.

In the question it makes the point that an element of this array can only have the value within the range of 0-9999. I can understand from the question that this restriction is what makes the whole thing possible and I should use it in my Algorithm in order to reach a solution. But I'm still getting nowhere. All the sorting Algorithms that I know of (Selection, Insertion, Merge, Quick ...)  all have running times larger than O(N) with the minimum being O(log N).

I can understand that some of these algorithms can have running times of O(N), but only on their best cases. But I don't think the question is being asked in that respect.

If anyone can shed any insight on this problem I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

[Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). O(4n) is O(n).

Answer (score 5):

Counting sort (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Only comparison sorts are Omega(n lg n).

Comment: @xtofl: Thanks :) I should point out though that Omega(n lg n) and O(n lg n) aren't the same thing - the first's a lower bound, whilst the second is an upper bound. The point is that comparison sorts are *at least* linearithmic in n. To beat n lg n, you have to sort another way.

Comment: How.  I wish I could +1 you even further, now.  It's just that Ω isn't on my keyboard :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Initialise an array `counts` of 10000 integers to 0.
2. Iterate over your data array `a` and increment `counts[a[i]]` in each iteration.
3. Iterate over `counts` and add `counts[i]` times the value `i` to the output array.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: you have 10,000 possible values. If you create a array of 10000 integers that hold a count, you can fill that array iterating over the original array, and then rebuild a new sorted array from that temporary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Allocate bitarray equal to size of 10000
2. Read the input
3. Set the bit-index equal value of the number you are reading.
4. Read Again the bitarray. If the bit is set then that index if your number in the sorted order.